# @font-face fonts within bootstrap css not displaying in firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I am able to display fonts in chrome, but not in firefox. I'm wondering if this is an issue because I'm using the bootstrap framework. Here's my code:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family:"bodyFont";
    src: url("http://caseymmiller.com/galapagos/fonts/museosans_300.otf");
}

body 
{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "bodyFont";
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Also, upon uploading it to my server, only one font is now appearing in chrome... and local sourcing wasn't working so I removed it. I am quite confused. http://caseymmiller.com/galapagos/bootstrapInvasive/Invasive.html

This is what I have in the css now. I tried what you listed before, but when sourcing both urls for each font, none of them would appear. That's why some are commented out right now. These are the sources that I want to use from now on.

```
@font-face
{
font-family:"headerFont";
src: url("http://livinggalapagos.org/static/Fonts/qhyts__.ttf");
/*src: url("http://livinggalapagos.org/static/Fonts/qhyts__.woff");*/

}

@font-face{
font-family:"subHeadFont";
src: url("http://livinggalapagos.org/static/Fonts/museosans_500.ttf");
src: url("http://livinggalapagos.org/static/Fonts/museosans_500.woff");

}

@font-face{
font-family:"bodyFont";
src: url("http://livinggalapagos.org/static/Fonts/museosans_300.ttf");
/*src: url("http://livinggalapagos.org/static/Fonts/museosans_300.woff");*/

}
```

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. I've already included the .ttf format. I changed the line to add a semicolon, but still no luck. Is that what you meant?

url('fonts/museosans_300-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype');

Comment: I figured that I would try and source them locally, but it wasn't working, so I sourced them using the url again.

Comment: They are all showing up in both chrome and safari now.

Answer (score 0):

`@font-face` is a complicated property. Here are some resources that might help you to code a "cross-browser" `@font-face`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/CSS/@font-face

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you don't have a typo in 2 of your properties?

```
src: url('fonts/museosans_300-.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
url('fonts/museosans_300-.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
```

Shouldn't these two be

```
src: url('fonts/museosans_300-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
url('fonts/museosans_300-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
```

Note the added **webfont** at the end of the file paths.

Be sure to clear your browser cache after making these changes as well.

Good luck!